# Pass list of specific objects when expecting the interfaces. How?

Tags: java, oop, generics, collections, interface

I have a `SomeClass implements InterfaceA`.
I have a method:

```
public void doSomething(List<SomeClass) objects);
```

Inside this method I want to call:

```
public void doProcessing(List<InterfaceA) o);
```

How can I do it?
The following does not work although `SomeClass` *isa* `InterfaceA`:

```
public void doSomething(List<SomeClass> objects){  

   doProcessing(objects);  

}
```

What is the standard way to handle this?

Comment: Assuming the lack of `>` everywhere is a typo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void doSomething(List<? extends InterfaceA> objects)
```

should work.

Read http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf , at least twice.

Answer (score 4):

Change signature of `doSomething` from

`public void doSomething(List<SomeClass> objects);`

to

`public void doSomething(List<InterfaceA> objects);`

or even better to

`public void doSomething(List<? extends InterfaceA> objects);`
(in this case you should change `doProcessing` too).

This means that both your methods work with interface, know the interface only  and do not care about the concrete implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Declarer the `doProcessing()` method in this way

```
public void doProcessing(List<? extends InterfaceA> o);
```